# Gradle sync failed: Cause: org.gradle.internal.logging.services.LoggingServiceRegistry

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

> Error:Unable to load class
>   'org.gradle.internal.logging.services.LoggingServiceRegistry'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's
>     dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network
>     connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies
>     and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle
>     build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may
>     solve this problem. Stop Gradle build
>     processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a
>     third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in
>     the project or the version of Gradle requested by the
>     project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can
>   also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I tried Invalidate Caches/Restart IDE this did not work.

Comment: Invalidate caches in Android Studio doesn't clear the Gradle cache, as far as I know

Comment: What should i do to resolve this issue ?

Comment: There are 3 options listed here. Sounds like you've only done one that was not sufficient. So try to 1) Upgrade Gradle and Android Studio if not done already 2) Delete the hidden `.gradle` folder in your user directory 3) Reboot your computer

Answer (score 1):

delete your `.gradle` folder from the user directory and try again.